# I want to implement a recyler view in the dialog

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, dialog

I made a recycler view inside the recycler view. And when I select the inside recycler view, the dialog is displayed, and I want to configure the recycler view in that dialog. I made a dialog and succeeded in displaying the dialog. but I don't know how to make a recycler view in a dialog. please help me.

Dialog class

```
public class RoomDialog extends Dialog {
    private EditText etStudentName, etStudentNumber;
    private Button btnConfirm, btnCancel;
    private Context context;
    private CustomDialogClickListener clickListener;
    private Retrofit retrofit;


    public EditText getEtStudentName() {
        return etStudentName;
    }

    public EditText getEtStudentNumber() {
        return etStudentNumber;
    }

    public Button getBtnConfirm() {
        return btnConfirm;
    }

    public Button getBtnCancel() {
        return btnCancel;
    }


    public RoomDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_room);
        etStudentName =  findViewById(R.id.et_room_Studentname);
        etStudentNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_room_studentNumber);
        btnConfirm = findViewById(R.id.btn_room_confrim);
        btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_room_cancel);


        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }) ;
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Inner recycler view

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<RoomData> rooms;
    public ArrayList<StudnetInRoomData> students;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RoomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomData> rooms) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_room, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoomData room = rooms.get(position);
        holder.tvRoomNum.setText(String.valueOf(room.roomNum));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rooms.size();
    }


    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvRoomNum;
        public TextView tvRoomTitle;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvRoomNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRoomNumber);
            tvRoomTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_room_title);

            tvRoomNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    RoomDialog roomDialog = new RoomDialog(context);
                    roomDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    roomDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    roomDialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    roomDialog.show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```